# Hide <td> from HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am trying to create a dynamic html table through JavaScript. I need to hide the teamid td (cell1). Need to set display as none. How can I do this?

```
function generate_table() 
{
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
    var teamrecord = "test";
    for (var i = 0; i <  teamrecord.length; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");

        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
        var cell2 = document.createElement("td");

        var cellText = document.createTextNode("teamrecord");
        var cellId = document.createTextNode("teamid");
        var radio = document.createElement("INPUT");
        radio.setAttribute("type", "radio");
        radio.setAttribute("name", "radio");

        cell.appendChild(cellText);
        cell1.appendChild(cellId);
        cell2.appendChild(radio);

        row.appendChild(cell);
        row.appendChild(cell1);
        row.appendChild(cell2);

        tblBody.appendChild(row);
    }

    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
    body.appendChild(tbl);
}
```

I use the following code but its not working

```
cell1.setAttribute("display","none");
```

Comment: What did your research come up with? Why didn't this work for you? WHat in specific didn't work?

Comment: @Peehaa I use this code snippet but there is no luck cell1.setAttribute("display","none");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like this:

```
cell1.style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the style `display` of required cell to `none`.

Add `cell1.style.display = 'none';` to your code.

**Working code below:**

```js
function generate_table() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var tbl = document.createElement("table");
  var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
  var teamrecord = "test";

  for (var i = 0; i < teamrecord.length; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
    var cell2 = document.createElement("td");

    var cellText = document.createTextNode("teamrecord");
    var cellId = document.createTextNode("teamid");
    var radio = document.createElement("INPUT");
    radio.setAttribute("type", "radio");
    radio.setAttribute("name", "radio");


    cell.appendChild(cellText);
    cell1.appendChild(cellId);
    cell2.appendChild(radio);

    cell1.style.display = 'none';

    row.appendChild(cell);
    row.appendChild(cell1);
    row.appendChild(cell2);

    tblBody.appendChild(row);
  }
  tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
  body.appendChild(tbl);

}
generate_table();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define it as a style like this:

```
cell1.style.display = 'none';
```

ref:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cell1.style.visibility = "hidden"`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.